# jsonify a SQLAlchemy result set in Flask

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to jsonify a SQLAlchemy result set in Flask/Python.

The Flask mailing list suggested the following method http://librelist.com/browser//flask/2011/2/16/jsonify-sqlalchemy-pagination-collection-result/#04a0754b63387f87e59dda564bde426e :

```
return jsonify(json_list = qryresult)
```

However I'm getting the following error back:

```
TypeError: <flaskext.sqlalchemy.BaseQuery object at 0x102c2df90> 
is not JSON serializable
```

What am I overlooking here?

I have found this question: [How to serialize SqlAlchemy result to JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5022066/how-to-serialize-sqlalchemy-result-to-json) which seems very similar however I didn't know whether Flask had some magic to make it easier as the mailing list post suggested.

Edit: for clarification, this is what my model looks like

```
class Rating(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'rating'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    fullurl = db.Column(db.String())
    url = db.Column(db.String())
    comments = db.Column(db.Text)
    overall = db.Column(db.Integer)
    shipping = db.Column(db.Integer)
    cost = db.Column(db.Integer)
    honesty = db.Column(db.Integer)
    communication = db.Column(db.Integer)
    name = db.Column(db.String())
    ipaddr = db.Column(db.String())
    date = db.Column(db.String())

    def __init__(self, fullurl, url, comments, overall, shipping, cost, honesty, communication, name, ipaddr, date):
        self.fullurl = fullurl
        self.url = url
        self.comments = comments
        self.overall = overall
        self.shipping = shipping
        self.cost = cost
        self.honesty = honesty
        self.communication = communication
        self.name = name
        self.ipaddr = ipaddr
        self.date = date
```

Comment: `jsonify(list(map(lambda x: x.to_dict(), qryresult)))`

Answer (score 185, accepted):

It seems that you actually haven't executed your query. Try following:

```
return jsonify(json_list = qryresult.all())
```

**[Edit]**: Problem with jsonify is, that usually the objects cannot be jsonified automatically. Even Python's datetime fails ;)

What I have done in the past, is adding an extra property (like `serialize`) to classes that need to be serialized.

```
def dump_datetime(value):
    """Deserialize datetime object into string form for JSON processing."""
    if value is None:
        return None
    return [value.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), value.strftime("%H:%M:%S")]

class Foo(db.Model):
    # ... SQLAlchemy defs here..
    def __init__(self, ...):
       # self.foo = ...
       pass

    @property
    def serialize(self):
       """Return object data in easily serializable format"""
       return {
           'id'         : self.id,
           'modified_at': dump_datetime(self.modified_at),
           # This is an example how to deal with Many2Many relations
           'many2many'  : self.serialize_many2many
       }
    @property
    def serialize_many2many(self):
       """
       Return object's relations in easily serializable format.
       NB! Calls many2many's serialize property.
       """
       return [ item.serialize for item in self.many2many]
```

And now for views I can just do:

```
return jsonify(json_list=[i.serialize for i in qryresult.all()])
```

**[Edit 2019]**:
In case you have more complex objects or circular references, use a library like [marshmallow](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io)).

Comment: Hmm, that has changed the error, now I'm getting the error referencing the SQLAlchemy object as in: `myapp.models.Rating object at 0x102f25c10&gt; is not JSON serializable`. Any clue? The object only contains Strings and Ints.

Comment: It seems that your Rating model contains relations to other objects, so please wait a sec, I'll update my answer..

Comment: It doesn't though, I've added my model definition to my original question. I appreciate your help!

Comment: Thanks! That's got it!! For anyone reading through this, the call should be `return jsonify(json_list=[i.serialize for i in qryresult.all()])` for the example given above (ie not `dump`).

Comment: @mwan100, thanks. In my original code I had `dump` property, no idea why I wanted to change that :S

Comment: Curious to know why you chose to make `serialize` a property rather than a function?

Comment: @Mohamed 7 years ago it made sense. I created `serialize` is a property because I did not need to push any arguments to it.. Of course, `as_json` would've been better name.

Comment: @plaes How would you deal with two models with many to many relationships that reference each other? For example a `User` model has `comments` and the `Comment` model has a `User` attached to it. If you call serialize on any of them, you get a recursion error.

Comment: I don't really deal with it. And this answer was just a quickie solution...

Comment: Flask's `jsonify` actually can handle `datetime`s now, but it may still be helpful to format them on your own since it returns them in RFC 822 format which is pretty unusual IMO. Docs: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.json.JSONEncoder

Answer (score 58):

Here's what's usually sufficient for me:

I create a serialization mixin which I use with my models. The serialization function basically fetches whatever attributes the SQLAlchemy inspector exposes and puts it in a dict.

```
from sqlalchemy.inspection import inspect

class Serializer(object):

    def serialize(self):
        return {c: getattr(self, c) for c in inspect(self).attrs.keys()}

    @staticmethod
    def serialize_list(l):
        return [m.serialize() for m in l]
```

All that's needed now is to extend the SQLAlchemy model with the `Serializer` mixin class.

If there are fields you do not wish to expose, or that need special formatting, simply override the `serialize()` function in the model subclass.

```
class User(db.Model, Serializer):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String)
    password = db.Column(db.String)

    # ...

    def serialize(self):
        d = Serializer.serialize(self)
        del d['password']
        return d
```

In your controllers, all you have to do is to call the `serialize()` function (or `serialize_list(l)` if the query results in a list) on the results:

```
def get_user(id):
    user = User.query.get(id)
    return json.dumps(user.serialize())

def get_users():
    users = User.query.all()
    return json.dumps(User.serialize_list(users))
```

Comment: If you are using jsonify for get_users, your syntax will need to be:  return jsonify( users = User.serialize_list( users ) )

Comment: I think this answer is way better than the others, thanks. `inspect()` is killer.

Comment: This works for me.

Comment: Fast and easy, thanks a lot !

Comment: This is nice solution. But it will not work for nested attributes that need serialization.

Comment: This is awesome, thank you!!

Comment: I had to customise the method serialize to skip my foreign keys, otherwise it shouts 'myForeignObject is not serializable'. (those attributes you set with db.relationship(...))

Answer (score 38):

I had the same need, to serialize into json.  Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441796/how-to-discover-table-properties-from-sqlalchemy-mapped-object). It shows how to discover columns programmatically.  So, from that I created the code below.  It works for me, and I'll be using it in my web app.

```
def to_json(inst, cls):
    """
    Jsonify the sql alchemy query result.
    """
    convert = dict()
    # add your coversions for things like datetime's 
    # and what-not that aren't serializable.
    d = dict()
    for c in cls.__table__.columns:
        v = getattr(inst, c.name)
        if c.type in convert.keys() and v is not None:
            try:
                d[c.name] = convert[c.type](v)
            except:
                d[c.name] = "Error:  Failed to covert using ", str(convert[c.type])
        elif v is None:
            d[c.name] = str()
        else:
            d[c.name] = v
    return json.dumps(d)

class Person(base):
    __tablename__ = 'person'
    id = Column(Integer, Sequence('person_id_seq'), primary_key=True)
    first_name = Column(Text)
    last_name = Column(Text)
    email = Column(Text)

    @property
    def json(self):
        return to_json(self, self.__class__)
```

Comment: This looks like a good fit for my current project, but I'm using non-declarative models. As such, it doesn't seem that I have access to `__table__` in the class even after mapping occurs. Any thoughts on how to adapt `to_json` for a non-declarative model?

Comment: I ended up just adding my own `Table` objects to each model (`__table__ = my_table_instance`) which seems to have worked.

Comment: Also you could extend the declarative Base class to include the `json` property in all your models automatically.

Comment: How do I get this to work with `datetime`? I ended up adding `sqlalchemy.sql.sqltypes.Date` to the `convert` dict, and then I changed every instance of `c.type` to `type(c.type)`.

Comment: @bitcycle In which cases will the column name be None?

Comment: Here's a similar solution: https://wakatime.com/blog/32-part-1-sqlalchemy-models-to-json

Answer (score 21):

Here's my approach:
https://github.com/n0nSmoker/SQLAlchemy-serializer

```
pip install SQLAlchemy-serializer
```

You can easily add mixin to your model and then just call
`.to_dict()` method on its instance.

You also can write your own mixin on base of `SerializerMixin`.

Comment: Interesting solution.  I had to add 
        elif isinstance(value, str):
            ret = value
before the elif hasattr(value, '__iter__'): in python3 to avoid infinite recursion

Comment: I also took out the if value: check in get_public because it was dropping integers = 0

Answer (score 7):

For a flat query (no joins) you can do this

```
@app.route('/results/')
def results():
    data = Table.query.all()
    result = [d.__dict__ for d in data]
    return jsonify(result=result)
```

and if you only want to return certain columns from the database you can do this

```
@app.route('/results/')
def results():
    cols = ['id', 'url', 'shipping']
    data = Table.query.all()
    result = [{col: getattr(d, col) for col in cols} for d in data]
    return jsonify(result=result)
```

Comment: worked for me as I used postgresql and had a table in it which I was querying on. Thanks a lot!

Comment: TypeError: Object of type InstanceState is not JSON serializable
is NOT a solution

Comment: I'm also hitting the same error as @fsalazar_sch: `TypeError: Object of type InstanceState is not JSON serializable`

Answer (score 6):

Ok, I've been working on this for a few hours, and I've developed what I believe to be the most pythonic solution yet. The following code snippets are python3 but shouldn't be too horribly painful to backport if you need.

The first thing we're gonna do is start with a mixin that makes your db models act kinda like `dict`s:

```
from sqlalchemy.inspection import inspect

class ModelMixin:
    """Provide dict-like interface to db.Model subclasses."""

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        """Expose object attributes like dict values."""
        return getattr(self, key)

    def keys(self):
        """Identify what db columns we have."""
        return inspect(self).attrs.keys()
```

Now we're going to define our model, inheriting the mixin:

```
class MyModel(db.Model, ModelMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    foo = db.Column(...)
    bar = db.Column(...)
    # etc ...
```

That's all it takes to be able to pass an instance of `MyModel()` to `dict()` and get a real live `dict` instance out of it, which gets us quite a long way towards making `jsonify()` understand it. Next, we need to extend `JSONEncoder` to get us the rest of the way:

```
from flask.json import JSONEncoder
from contextlib import suppress

class MyJSONEncoder(JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        # Optional: convert datetime objects to ISO format
        with suppress(AttributeError):
            return obj.isoformat()
        return dict(obj)

app.json_encoder = MyJSONEncoder
```

Bonus points: if your model contains computed fields (that is, you want your JSON output to contain fields that aren't actually stored in the database), that's easy too. Just define your computed fields as `@property`s, and extend the `keys()` method like so:

```
class MyModel(db.Model, ModelMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    foo = db.Column(...)
    bar = db.Column(...)

    @property
    def computed_field(self):
        return 'this value did not come from the db'

    def keys(self):
        return super().keys() + ['computed_field']
```

Now it's trivial to jsonify:

```
@app.route('/whatever', methods=['GET'])
def whatever():
    return jsonify(dict(results=MyModel.query.all()))
```

Comment: I think your answer somehow like what I did.

Comment: Nice answer because it works with original flask.jsonify()

Answer (score 5):

If you are using `flask-restful` you can use [marshal](http://flask-restful-cn.readthedocs.org/en/0.3.4/fields.html):

```
from flask.ext.restful import Resource, fields, marshal

topic_fields = {
    'title':   fields.String,
    'content': fields.String,
    'uri':     fields.Url('topic'),
    'creator': fields.String,
    'created': fields.DateTime(dt_format='rfc822')
}

class TopicListApi(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return {'topics': [marshal(topic, topic_fields) for topic in DbTopic.query.all()]}
```

You need to explicitly list what you are returning and what type it is, which I prefer anyway for an api. Serialization is easily taken care of (no need for `jsonify`), dates are also not a problem. Note that the content for the `uri` field is automatically generated based on the `topic` endpoint and the id.

Answer (score 4):

Here's my answer if you're using the declarative base (with help from some of the answers already posted):

```
# in your models definition where you define and extend declarative_base()
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
...
Base = declarative_base()
Base.query = db_session.query_property()
...

# define a new class (call "Model" or whatever) with an as_dict() method defined
class Model():
    def as_dict(self):
        return { c.name: getattr(self, c.name) for c in self.__table__.columns }

# and extend both the Base and Model class in your model definition, e.g.
class Rating(Base, Model):
    ____tablename__ = 'rating'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    fullurl = db.Column(db.String())
    url = db.Column(db.String())
    comments = db.Column(db.Text)
    ...

# then after you query and have a resultset (rs) of ratings
rs = Rating.query.all()

# you can jsonify it with
s = json.dumps([r.as_dict() for r in rs], default=alchemyencoder)
print (s)

# or if you have a single row
r = Rating.query.first()

# you can jsonify it with
s = json.dumps(r.as_dict(), default=alchemyencoder)

# you will need this alchemyencoder where your are calling json.dumps to handle datetime and decimal format
# credit to Joonas @ http://codeandlife.com/2014/12/07/sqlalchemy-results-to-json-the-easy-way/
def alchemyencoder(obj):
    """JSON encoder function for SQLAlchemy special classes."""
    if isinstance(obj, datetime.date):
        return obj.isoformat()
    elif isinstance(obj, decimal.Decimal):
        return float(obj)
```

Answer (score 4):

`Flask-Restful` `0.3.6` [the Request Parsing](https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reqparse.html) recommend marshmallow

> marshmallow is an ORM/ODM/framework-agnostic library for converting
>   complex datatypes, such as objects, to and from native Python
>   datatypes.

A simple [marshmallow](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0/index.html) example is showing below.

```
from marshmallow import Schema, fields

class UserSchema(Schema):
    name = fields.Str()
    email = fields.Email()
    created_at = fields.DateTime()

from marshmallow import pprint

user = User(name="Monty", email="monty@python.org")
schema = UserSchema()
result = schema.dump(user)
pprint(result)
# {"name": "Monty",
#  "email": "monty@python.org",
#  "created_at": "2014-08-17T14:54:16.049594+00:00"}
```

The core features contain

> Declaring Schemas
>   Serializing Objects (“Dumping”)
>   Deserializing Objects (“Loading”)
>   Handling Collections of Objects
>   Validation
>   Specifying Attribute Names
>   Specifying Serialization/Deserialization Keys
>   Refactoring: Implicit Field Creation
>   Ordering Output
>   “Read-only” and “Write-only” Fields
>   Specify Default Serialization/Deserialization Values
>   Nesting Schemas
>   Custom Fields

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way to add an as_dict() method on every class, as well as any other method you want to have on every single class.
Not sure if this is the desired way or not, but it works...

```
class Base(object):
    def as_dict(self):
        return dict((c.name,
                     getattr(self, c.name))
                     for c in self.__table__.columns)


Base = declarative_base(cls=Base)
```

Answer (score 2):

I've been looking at this problem for the better part of a day, and here's what I've come up with (credit to https://stackoverflow.com/a/5249214/196358 for pointing me in this direction).

(Note: I'm using flask-sqlalchemy, so my model declaration format is a bit different from straight sqlalchemy).

In my `models.py` file:

```
import json

class Serializer(object):
  __public__ = None
  "Must be implemented by implementors"

  def to_serializable_dict(self):
    dict = {}
    for public_key in self.__public__:
      value = getattr(self, public_key)
      if value:
        dict[public_key] = value
    return dict

class SWEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
  def default(self, obj):
    if isinstance(obj, Serializer):
      return obj.to_serializable_dict()
    if isinstance(obj, (datetime)):
      return obj.isoformat()
    return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)


def SWJsonify(*args, **kwargs):
  return current_app.response_class(json.dumps(dict(*args, **kwargs), cls=SWEncoder, indent=None if request.is_xhr else 2), mimetype='application/json')
  # stolen from https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/blob/master/flask/helpers.py
```

and all my model objects look like this:

```
class User(db.Model, Serializer):
  __public__ = ['id','username']
  ... field definitions ...
```

In my views I call SWJsonify wherever I would have called `Jsonify`, like so:

```
@app.route('/posts')
def posts():
  posts = Post.query.limit(PER_PAGE).all()
  return SWJsonify({'posts':posts })
```

Seems to work pretty well. Even on relationships. I haven't gotten far with it, so YMMV, but  so far it feels pretty "right" to me.

Suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for something like the rails approach used in ActiveRecord to_json and implemented something similar using this Mixin after being unsatisfied with other suggestions.  It handles nested models, and including or excluding attributes of the top level or nested models.

```
class Serializer(object):

    def serialize(self, include={}, exclude=[], only=[]):
        serialized = {}
        for key in inspect(self).attrs.keys():
            to_be_serialized = True
            value = getattr(self, key)
            if key in exclude or (only and key not in only):
                to_be_serialized = False
            elif isinstance(value, BaseQuery):
                to_be_serialized = False
                if key in include:
                    to_be_serialized = True
                    nested_params = include.get(key, {})
                    value = [i.serialize(**nested_params) for i in value]

            if to_be_serialized:
                serialized[key] = value

        return serialized
```

Then, to get the BaseQuery serializable I extended BaseQuery

```
class SerializableBaseQuery(BaseQuery):

    def serialize(self, include={}, exclude=[], only=[]):
        return [m.serialize(include, exclude, only) for m in self]
```

For the following models

```
class ContactInfo(db.Model, Serializer):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    full_name = db.Column(db.String())
    source = db.Column(db.String())
    source_id = db.Column(db.String())

    email_addresses = db.relationship('EmailAddress', backref='contact_info', lazy='dynamic')
    phone_numbers = db.relationship('PhoneNumber', backref='contact_info', lazy='dynamic')


class EmailAddress(db.Model, Serializer):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email_address = db.Column(db.String())
    type = db.Column(db.String())
    contact_info_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('contact_info.id'))


class PhoneNumber(db.Model, Serializer):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    phone_number = db.Column(db.String())
    type = db.Column(db.String())
    contact_info_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('contact_info.id'))

    phone_numbers = db.relationship('Invite', backref='phone_number', lazy='dynamic')
```

You could do something like

```
@app.route("/contact/search", methods=['GET'])
def contact_search():
    contact_name = request.args.get("name")
    matching_contacts = ContactInfo.query.filter(ContactInfo.full_name.like("%{}%".format(contact_name)))

    serialized_contact_info = matching_contacts.serialize(
        include={
            "phone_numbers" : {
                "exclude" : ["contact_info", "contact_info_id"]
            },
            "email_addresses" : {
                "exclude" : ["contact_info", "contact_info_id"]
            }
        }
    )

    return jsonify(serialized_contact_info)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was working with a sql query defaultdict of lists of RowProxy objects named jobDict
It took me a while to figure out what Type the objects were.

This was a really simple quick way to resolve to some clean jsonEncoding just by typecasting the row to a list and by initially defining the dict with a value of list.

```
    jobDict = defaultdict(list)
    def set_default(obj):
        # trickyness needed here via import to know type
        if isinstance(obj, RowProxy):
            return list(obj)
        raise TypeError


    jsonEncoded = json.dumps(jobDict, default=set_default)
```

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add my method to do this.

just define a custome json encoder to serilize your db models.

```
class ParentEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        # convert object to a dict
        d = {}
        if isinstance(obj, Parent):
            return {"id": obj.id, "name": obj.name, 'children': list(obj.child)}
        if isinstance(obj, Child):
            return {"id": obj.id, "name": obj.name}

        d.update(obj.__dict__)
        return d
```

then in your view function

```
parents = Parent.query.all()
dat = json.dumps({"data": parents}, cls=ParentEncoder)
resp = Response(response=dat, status=200, mimetype="application/json")
return (resp)
```

it works well though the parent have relationships

Answer (score -1):

It's been a lot of times and there are lots of valid answers, but the following code block seems to work:

```
my_object = SqlAlchemyModel()
my_serializable_obj = my_object.__dict__
del my_serializable_obj["_sa_instance_state"]
print(jsonify(my_serializable_object))
```

I'm aware that this is not a perfect solution, nor as elegant as the others, however for those who want o quick fix, they might try this.