# What is the proper model definition for SQLAlchemy to avoid error message : AttributeError: 'InstrumentedList' object has no attribute'?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-login

I am creating a Point of Sales application, with the typical data hierarchy :
Company->branches->Sales->SaleData, this is the model definition (Note that, the User model already prepare and working as a flask-login compatible model) :

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from main import db
from collections import OrderedDict


class Users(db.Model,object):                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    '''                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    Adding object to trun sqlalchemy into json object                                                                                                                                                                             
    '''                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)                                                                                                                                                                                  
    username = db.Column(db.String(60), unique=True)                                                                                                                                                                              
    firstname = db.Column(db.String(20))                                                                                                                                                                                          
    lastname = db.Column(db.String(20))                                                                                                                                                                                           
    password = db.Column(db.String)                                                                                                                                                                                               
    email = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True)                                                                                                                                                                                
    role = db.Column(db.String(20))                                                                                                                                                                                               
    active = db.Column(db.Boolean)                                                                                                                                                                                                
    company_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('companies.id'))                                                                                                                                                             

    def __init__(self, username=None, password=None, email=None, firstname=None, lastname=None):                                                                                                                                  
        self.username = username                                                                                                                                                                                                  
        self.email = email                                                                                                                                                                                                        
        self.firstname = firstname                                                                                                                                                                                                
        self.lastname = lastname                                                                                                                                                                                                  
        self.password = password                                                                                                                                                                                                  
        self.active = True                                                                                                                                                                                                        
        self.role = 'Admin'                                                                                                                                                                                                       

    def is_authenticated(self):                                                                                                                                                                                                   
        return True                                                                                                                                                                                                               

    def is_active(self):                                                                                                                                                                                                          
        return self.active                                                                                                                                                                                                        

    def is_anonymous(self):                                                                                                                                                                                                       
        return False                                                                                                                                                                                                              

    def get_id(self):                                                                                                                                                                                                             
        return unicode(self.id)                                                                                                                                                                                                   

    def _asdict(self):                                                                                                                                                                                                            
        '''                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
        Thanks to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7102754/jsonify-a-sqlalchemy-result-set-in-flask                                                                                                                             
    '''                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
        result = OrderedDict()                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        for key in self.__mapper__.c.keys():                                                                                                                                                                                      
            result[key] = getattr(self, key)                                                                                                                                                                                      
        return result 


class Companies(db.Model):                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True)                                                                                                                                                                                 
    address = db.Column(db.String)                                                                                                                                                                                                
    users = db.relation('Users', backref=db.backref('users'))                                                                                                                                                                     
    token = db.Column(db.String) #for identification of client                                                                                                                                                                    
    branches = db.relationship("Branches")                                                                                                                                                                                        

    def __init__(self, name=None, address=None, token=None):                                                                                                                                                                      
        self.name = name                                                                                                                                                                                                          
        self.address = address                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        self.token = token             

class Branches(db.Model):                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)                                                                                                                                                                                  
    name = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True)                                                                                                                                                                                 
    address = db.Column(db.String)                                                                                                                                                                                                
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))                                                                                                                                                                    
    token = db.Column(db.String) #for identification of client                                                                                                                                                                    
    company_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('companies.id'))                                                                        
    sales = db.relation('Sales',                                                                                                                                                                                                  
                    backref=db.backref('sales', lazy='dynamic'),                                                                                                                                                              
                    cascade="all, delete-orphan",                                                                                                                                                                             
                    lazy='dynamic',                                                                                                                                                                                           
                    passive_deletes=True)                                                                                                                                                                                     

    def __init__(self, name=None, address=None, token=None, user_id=None):                                                                                                                                                        
        self.name = name                                                                                                                                                                                                          
        self.address = address                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        self.token = token                                                                                                                                                                                                        
        self.user_id = user_id                                                                                                                                                                                                    

class Sales(db.Model):                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)                                                                                                                                                                                  
    day = db.Column(db.Date)                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    branch_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('branches.id'))                                                                                                                                                               
    data = db.relationship("SaleData")                                                                                                                                                                                            

    def __init__(self, day=None):                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        self.day = day                                                                                                                                                                                                            

class SaleData(db.Model):                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)                                                                                                                                                                                  
    sale_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('sales.id'))                                                                                                                                                                    
    cash_start_of_day = db.Column(db.Integer)                                                                                                                                                                                     
    cash_end_of_day = db.Column(db.Integer)                                                                                                                                                                                       
    income = db.Column(db.Integer) # which is end - start                                                                                                                                                                         

    def __init__(self, cash_start_of_day = None, cash_end_of_day = None, income = None):                                                                                                                                          
        self.cash_start_of_day = cash_start_of_day                                                                                                                                                                                
        self.cash_end_of_day = cash_end_of_day                                                                                                                                                                                    
        self.income = income
```

Now, if I try to add a Sales data to the branches, it didn't happen if I do this :

```
 branch1 = company1.branches.filter().all()
```

I can olny do this :

```
 branch1 = company1.branches[0]
```

If not using that `[]` operator, I got error message : AttributeError: 'InstrumentedList' object has no attribute'. I have already browse another answer here in SO, it got to do with that `lazy` things in backref definition, so I already modify my current model

But it seems like I am missing something here.. any clue?
Thanks!

**EDIT 1 : Unit test added & User Model added too**

I already got a concise answer from Mark Hildreth, and it saves me a lot! Because of that, I am going to put here the complete unit test of this model. I am sure it will help newbies out there in their very first step in SQLAlchemy. So, here goes :

```
import unittest
from main import db
import models
import md5
import helper


class DbTest(unittest.TestCase):                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    def setUp(self):                                                                                                                                                                                                              
        db.drop_all()                                                                                                                                                                                                             
        db.create_all()                                                                                                                                                                                                           

    def test_user_and_company(self):                                                                                                                                                                                              
        """admin of a company"""                                                                                                                                                                                                  

        user1 = models.Users('eko', helper.hash_pass('rahasia'), 'swdev.bali@gmail.com')                                                                                                                                          
        db.session.add(user1)                                                                                                                                                                                                     
        db.session.commit()                                                                                                                                                                                                       

        """the company"""                                                                                                                                                                                                         
        company1 = models.Companies('CDI','Glagah Kidul', 'empty')                                                                                                                                                                
        db.session.add(company1)                                                                                                                                                                                                  
        company1.users.append(user1)                                                                                                                                                                                              
        db.session.commit()                                                                                                                                                                                                       
        assert company1.users[0].id == user1.id                                                                                                                                                                                   

        """branches"""                                                                                                                                                                                                            
        company1.branches.append(models.Branches(name='Kopjar',address='Penjara Malaysia', token='empty token', user_id=user1.id))                                                                                                
        company1.branches.append(models.Branches(name='Selangor',address='Koperasi Selangor', token='empty token',  user_id=user1.id))                                                                                            
        db.session.commit()                                                                                                                                                                                                       

        '''sales'''
        branch1 = company1.branches.filter(models.Branches.name=='Kopjar').first()
        assert branch1.name=='Kopjar' and branch1.company_id == company1.id


        sale = models.Sales(day='2013-02-02')
        sale.data.append(models.SaleData(cash_start_of_day = 0, cash_end_of_day = 500000, income = 500000))
        branch1.sales.append(sale)
        db.session.commit()

        assert sale.id is not None


    if __name__ == '__main__':                                                                                                                                                                                                        
        unittest.main()
```

There may be bad practice in this model or unit test, and I will be delighted if you point that out :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may wish to review the ["Collection Configuration"](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/collections.html) section of the documentation. There are a few main, built-in ways to deal with how relationships are handled in SQLAlchemy, and that section of the documentation shows the various ways.

By default, when you have...

```
class Companies(db.Model):                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    ...
    branches = db.relationship("Branches")                                                                                                                                                                                        
    ...
```

Loading a Company will load all of the branches in (and by default, it loads them into a list). Therefore, after retrieving a company, `company.branches` returns to you a list of branches. Because it is a list, it doesn't have functions such as `filter()` or `all()`. If you are not expecting a large list of branches, this might be preferred since it might make more sense for you to use branches as a list rather than as a query object. Having this as a list allows you to do things such as...

```
company = session.query(Companies).first()
my_branch = Branches(...)
company.branches.append(my_branch)
session.commit()
```

This will properly create the new `Branches` object without needing to add it specifically to the session (which I think is pretty nifty).

As a side note, if you were to do `type(company.branches)`, you would not get `<type 'list'>`, because in order to pull off this magic, SQLAlchemy will actually set `branches` to an object type that works LIKE a list, but actually has additional SQLAlchemy-specific info. This object type, if you haven't guessed, is the "InstrumentedList" that you are getting the error message about.

However, you might not want to do this; specifically, this requires you to load in all of the branches at once, and you might only want to load a few in at a time because you have thousands of them (thousands of branches in a company, just imagine the bureaucracy...)

So, you change the relation, [as the docs say](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/collections.html#dynamic-relationship-loaders)...

> A key feature to enable management of a large collection is the
>   so-called “dynamic” relationship. This is an optional form of
>   relationship() which returns a Query object in place of a collection
>   when accessed. filter() criterion may be applied as well as limits and
>   offsets, either explicitly or via array slices:

It appears that this is what you want to do if you want to be able to do things like `company.branches.filter(...).all()`. To do this, you would do as the docs show, by making the `lazy` attribute of the relationship "dynamic"...

```
class Companies(db.Model):                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    ...
    branches = db.relationship("Branches", lazy='dynamic')                                                                                                                                                                                        
    ...
```

It looks like you've done this already for the branches -> sales relationship, but you haven't for the company -> branches relationship, which is what is giving you the error.

Comment: Sir, you give me a big smile in this morning... A complete and concise answer. I can't expect to have better answer than your answer. Therefore, I also completed my question with User model (which I ommited previously) and a unit test that use these models. That's my way of doing the unit test. Do you see any bad practice there? :) Thank you so much!

Comment: A note on the unit test, yes, my database is still in heavy development, so I didn't expect to save previous database. Or in other words, I didn't use transaction here. I also need to have my database populated with the unit test result

Comment: If you're looking for feedback on your unit tests, I would suggest posting on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Also, I've had my writing called many things before, but "concise" is rarely among them :P

Comment: Thanks @mark! Well, rarely doesn't mean never than ;) Great for that codereview site. I just knew it...