# py-flask-jsontools how to serialize sqlalchemy model or list of model

Tags: python, json, flask, sqlalchemy

the "how to serialize a sqlalchemy model" has many solutions.  many of which change as parts and pieces get changed by flask.

[jsonify a SQLAlchemy result set in Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7102754/jsonify-a-sqlalchemy-result-set-in-flask)

i've settled on using py-flask-jsontools.  made a copy of the repository and integrated several fixes from various forks.  the orginal author seems mia.

https://github.com/slippers/py-flask-jsontools

here is the test for sqlalchemy i made to explore serializing to json with and without flask context.

https://github.com/slippers/py-flask-jsontools/blob/master/tests/sqlalchemy-test.py

? how do I serialize sqlalchemy model to json without calling

```
json.dumps( "some query object", cls=DynamicJSONEncoder)
```

especially when there is request context and flask knows what serializer class to use.

Comment: You mean without calling it every time? Have you tried adding what is necessary in after_request of app?

Comment: my expectation was that if i simply just return the alchemy object it would serialize to json

Answer (score 0):

extend the JsonResponse to call dumps with the DynamicJSONEncoder. JsonResponse has optional params for different http response codes and headers.

```
class SqlAlchemyResponse(JsonResponse):
    def preprocess_response_data(self, response):
        return json.dumps(response, cls=DynamicJSONEncoder)

@app.route('/person', methods=['GET']) 
def list_persons():
    rs = self.session.query(Person).all()
    return SqlAlchemyResponse(rs)
```