# jquery autocomplete issues serializing data properly

Tags: python, json, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am trying to implement jQuery autocomplete and am unable to pass objects so they have all the information available in my html. I am trying to follow [Carl Ekerot's Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7102754/jsonify-a-sqlalchemy-result-set-in-flask/14322313), but am unable to serialize this properly. In my template I get no suggestions in the drop down when I type in entries to search. The database is returning several entries properly so the problem must lie somewhere in how it is serializing the data.

Here is a link to the [jQuery Autocomplete Documentation](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote) I am trying to implement.

models.py

```
class Serializer(object):
    def serialize(self):
        return {c: getattr(self, c) for c in inspect(self).attrs.keys()}

    @staticmethod
    def serialize_list(l):
        return [m.serialize() for m in l]

class User(db.Model, Serializer):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(32), index=True, unique=True, nullable=False)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=False)
    #active=db.Column(db.Boolean, default=True)
    admin = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    last_seen = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    roles=db.relationship('Role', backref='user')
    replies_sent=db.relationship('Message_Reply', backref='from_user')
    group_admins=db.relationship('Group',
                                secondary='admined',
                                primaryjoin=(admined.c.user_id==id),
                                backref='admins')
    messages=db.relationship('Message_User', backref='user')
    groups=db.relationship('Group',
                                secondary='grouped',
                                primaryjoin=(grouped.c.user_id==id),
                                backref='users')
    permissions = db.relationship('Permission',
                                secondary=permissioned,
                                primaryjoin=(permissioned.c.user_id==id),
                                backref='users')

    def serialize(self):
        d = Serializer.serialize(self)
        del d['password_hash']
        del d['admin']
        del d['roles']
        del d['replies_sent']
        del d['group_admins']
        del d['messages']
        del d['groups']
        del d['permissions']
        del d['last_seen']
        return d
```

views.py

```
@app.route("/search", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def search():
    print request.args
    try:
        term=request.args['term']
        data=User.query.filter(User.username.like('%'+term+'%')).all()
        '''
        q=[]
        for i in data:
            q.append(i.username)
        '''
    except:
        return jsonify('fail')
    print User.serialize_list(data)
    return json.dumps(User.serialize_list(data))
    #return json.dumps(data.serialize())
    #return jsonify('a')

'''
def get_user(id):
    user = User.query.get(id)
    return json.dumps(user.serialize())

def get_users():
    users = User.query.all()
    return json.dumps(User.serialize_list(users))
  '''
```

scripts.js

```
$( function() {
    function log( message ) {
        $( "<div>" ).text( message ).prependTo( "#log" );
        $( "#log" ).scrollTop( 0 );
    }

    $("#birds").autocomplete({
        source: "/search",
        minLength: 1,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            log("Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id);
        }
    });
});
```

template.html

```
<div class="ui-widget">
  <input id="birds" class="form-control"  placeholder="Users">
</div>

<div class="ui-widget" style="margin-top:2em; font-family:Arial">
  Result:
  <div id="log" style="height: 200px; width: 300px; overflow: auto;" class="ui-widget-content"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What's the problem, then? Iow what did you get as a result, and what did you expect instead?

Comment: When I type in the suggestion box I get empty suggestions. The database is returning multiple entries correctly, but they don't show up in the suggestions.

Comment: The problem might be that you use `json.dumps` instead of  `jsonify(User.serialize_list(data))`. The difference is the latter sets proper content-type; some newer browsers/jquery combinations might render the response with a wrong (i.e. not json) content-type header not working.