# SQLAlchemy query returns a tuple and I need it to be a JSON

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I was doing this SQLAlchemy and pyodbc connection, but when I get my data from query it returns a tuple list without key, only value.

For example

```
[(valueOfObjectsSeparatedByComa), (valueOfObjectsSeparatedByComa), etc..]
```

This is my code.

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
import sqlalchemy as sa
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import json
from json import dumps
from flask.ext.jsonpify import jsonify
import pyodbc

client = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQLSERVERDRIVER};SERVER=serverName;DATABASE=database;UID=user;PWD=password')

class Users(Resource):
    def get(self):
        query =("select * from SEC_User")
        try:
            result = client.execute(query).fetchall()
            return jsonify(result)
        except Exception as e:
            client.close()
            raise e


api.add_resource(Users, '/users') # Route_1
```

When I do a `print(result)` I can  see the data in tuple format and only the value not the key, for example, instead of `"name": "john"` `[(john), (james)]` the correct would be `[{name: jonh}, {name: james}]`.

What can I do to change the tuple data?

Comment: Not sure if this is a duplicate of [How to serialize SqlAlchemy result to JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5022066/how-to-serialize-sqlalchemy-result-to-json), or [Convert sqlalchemy row object to python dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958219/convert-sqlalchemy-row-object-to-python-dict). Both apply, though you're also using flask, so maybe [jsonify a SQLAlchemy result set in Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7102754/jsonify-a-sqlalchemy-result-set-in-flask)?

Comment: i will try the "How to serialize SqlAlchemy result to JSON" i hope that works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to serialize SqlAlchemy result to JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5022066/how-to-serialize-sqlalchemy-result-to-json)